# How to set different row height which is dynamically loaded

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

Hi guys I have situation, where I am loading table rows dynamically. The code that set table row is like:

```
var rows = [];
_.each(records, function(rec) {
        var row = Alloy.createController('myRow', rec).getView();
        rows.push(row);
    });
}

$.myaTable.setData(rows);
```

I have different value in each row. And I want to set row height to fit the texts. I tried to set the row height

```
"TableViewRow": {
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE
}
```

I also changed the myRow.js like `$.myRow.height = Ti.UI.SIZE`.

But the problem - it is applying same height of to all rows. I show below in image:

**Current Output:**

[image: The Out put]

**My need is:**

[image: My need]

**EDIT:**

myRow.xml:

```
<TableViewRow id="ideaRow">
    <View id="content">
        <Label id="myTitle"></Label>
        <Label id="myDesc"></Label>
        <View id="control">
          <View id="Control1" />
          <View id="Control2" />
          <View id="Control3" />
        </View>
    </View>
<TableViewRow>
```

myRow.js:

```
$. myTitle.text = args.title
$. myDesc.text = args.description
```

Do you think any solutions exists in Titanium for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Inside of your `myRow` controller. how are you instantiating row objects?

Comment: Josaih, I edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your exact problem with 3.3.0.GA.

On iOS, the tableViewRows automatically fill up the whole screen without any TSS. This is because the Views inside your myRow.xml are set to Ti.UI.FILL by Titanium's default.  The solution is to make sure you set height: Ti.UI.SIZE for your  tags inside the myRow.xml

Comment: I accept phil your feedback. One of view Control1 was taking height of largest row and applies same for all control in all rows. I have to define the height of Contrl1 to specific. It can be fixed some size or Ti.UI.SIZE